# Timed out waiting for process to appear on emulator-5554

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having the problem when running apps on a device or emulator with Android Studio 3.6.2

```
Launching 'app' on Android TV (1080p) API 22.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.xxx.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Timed out waiting for process (xxx) to appear on emulator-5554.
```

And apps do not open,I try the [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245771/timed-out-waiting-for-process-to-appear-on-device)

do not work for me , anything to do?

Comment: When you go to logcat and change the 3rd dropdown to `error` what do you see?

Comment: I see . I used the rabbitmq and the problem just like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201745/failed-to-create-connectionfactory-object